# Which hibernate.dialect for DB2?

Tags: hibernate, db2, liferay, dialect

I use Liferay 6.2 and DB2 10.5.

I would like to set the *hibernate.dialect* property.

[Here](http://javabeat.net/list-of-hibernate-sql-dialects/) I can find the dialect depending on DB2 distribution

```
DB2         org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
DB2 AS/400  org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect
DB2 OS390   org.hibernate.dialect.DB2390Dialect
```

But I can not find anywhere the mapping between DB2 version and those names: *AS/400* or *OS390* or just *DB2*.

Which dialect should I choose ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging more into AS/400 and OS/390, I must obviously use `org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect`because AS/400 was introduced in 1988 and OS/390 in 1995.

Comment: I will be able to do it tomorrow